# mongoimport query for upsert the fields

Tags: mongodb

I have record like this

```
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "big datamatica", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }
```

I need to update like this

```
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "google", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }
```

when i use import

```
mongoimport -d durga -c prasad --upsert --upsertFields name,company,size,role sample.json
```

I able to get

```
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "big datamatica", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }
{ "name" : "durga prasad", "company" : "google", "size" : 50, "role" : "CEO" }
```

I am getting both the records I need updated record only
If the field not exists it should add to the existing record

Comment: On the basis of which fields you want to update the record? you have mentioned all the fields in your command that will insert new records only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update the company value. You shouldn't mention it in the `upsertFields`.

```
mongoimport -d durga -c prasad --upsert --upsertFields name,size,role sample.json
```

Also, to update the documents, you can fire queries on the mongo shell directly.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--upsertFields):

> Specifies a list of fields for the query portion of the upsert

Comment: hi 4j41 check my import statement correctly, company field added

Comment: And, I am saying it shouldn't be added.

Comment: oh still, Its not updated...! the files that i have in the json file are inserted into the existing collection the records are not updated! may i know the exact solution...

Comment: In my collection I have ({ name : "durga prasad", company : "IBM", size : 5000, role : "assistant manager" })

Comment: Then, just use the name `mongoimport -d durga -c prasad --upsert --upsertFields name sample.json`

Comment: after mongoimport i need to update that record with the json file (or)

Comment: If the record not existed it should add to the collection